# Scala: Get every combination of the last 24 months

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combinations

I'm trying to generate a DataFrame in Spark (but perhaps just Scala is enough) in which I have every combination of the last 24 months where the second year-month is always > the first year-month.

For example, it is the 1 March 2019 as of writing this, I'm after something like:

```scala
List(
(2017, 3, 2017, 4),
(2017, 3, 2017, 5),
(2017, 3, 2017, 6),
// ..
(2017, 3, 2019, 3),
(2017, 4, 2017, 5),
// ..
(2019, 1, 2019, 3),
(2019, 2, 2019, 3),
)
```

Comment: Are you able to list every single month of the last 2 years ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easiest done with pure Scala without involving Spark. First, compute the list of all (year, month) tuples of the last 24 months. This can be done by using `java.time` and a Stream as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDate

val numMonths = 24
val now = LocalDate.now()
val startTime = now.minusMonths(numMonths)

lazy val dateStream: Stream[LocalDate] = startTime #:: dateStream.map(_.plusMonths(1))
val dates = dateStream.take(numMonths + 1).toSeq.map(t => (t.getYear(), t.getMonth().getValue()))
```

Next, simply find all the 2-combinations of this tuple-sequence. This will automatically fulfill the condition that the second month should be after the first.

```
val datePerms = dates.combinations(2).map(c => (c(0)._1, c(0)._2, c(1)._1, c(1)._2))
```

You can easily convert this to a dataframe with the `toDF` method if necessary.